# reportlab barchart categoryAxis below zero

Tags: bar-chart, reportlab

How to display "categoryAxis" not in 0?

I have negative values in my chart but "categoryAxis" is always on 0 position.

For example: 
I have minimum value -4.50 and I would like "categoryAxis" on that position.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set valueMin less than 0 for valueAxis
For example valueAxis.valueMin = -5
categoryAxis it is for Category not for data

```
bc = VerticalBarChart()
...
bc.valueAxis.valueMin = -5 (or set it dynamically)
bc.valueAxis.valueMax = 50
bc.valueAxis.valueStep = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but if you mean x labels instead of "categorieAxis", you can set the labels at the bottom (and not at 0 position) as the following:

```
bc.categoryAxis.labelAxisMode = 'low'
```